# Why is the number of electrons in a silicon bar dependent on cross-section, when we inject electrons into it?

Tags: silicon, injection-current

I am asked the following question:
In Example 2.9, compute the total number
of electrons “stored” in the material from
`x = 0` to `x = L`. Assume the cross section
area of the bar is equal to a.

[image]

My answer was N*L/2. Basically the area under the concentration profile.  Then, I happily look at the solutions and the answer is different:
[image]

Why is the result multiplied by the cross-section of the bar?

My understanding is that we inject a finite amount of electrons into the bar. So, despite the cross-sectional area of the bar, "area under the curve" amount of electrons will be stored in the bar.

It seems, I am not understanding something...

Comment: Check your text's definition of "electron concentration" ... is it in the form of a density, i.e. electrons/unit volume?

Comment: Yes, it is for example `10^10 carriers/cm^3`

Comment: There's your answer then. To get from a density to a number(population), you need a volume.

Comment: "*...inject a **finite amount of electrons** into the bar*". This is not mentioned in the screenshot of the question. It refers to concentration (number per unit volume) only. To get "*number*" from "*number per unit volume*", wouldn't it make sense to multiply by  volume (here: area times length) to get the units correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have provided the 1D solution when the question asks for the solution in 3D.

Since the electron distribution is not dependent on z or y you it will be equivalent to multiply your solution by the cross sectional area.

To see this you can compute this:

$$ \#Electron =  \int_{-z}^z \int_{-y}^y \int_0^L n(x) dxdydz $$

and remember that $$a = yz$$

and you should get the answer you are looking for.